# Kotlin class for API data

Tags: android, kotlin

I have API data with following structure:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "a3d9b20a-f84c-483e-81af-f8d6a7e2de0f",
            "amount": 11000,
            "transport": 29000,
            "total": 183000,
            "weight": 14,
            "payment": "Cash",
            "payment_id": null,
            "payment_method": null,
            "accepted": 0,
            "customer": {
                "id": "2c8693d9-76ff-4bad-b7bd-bc3a1446a5e5",
                "name": "Admin",
                "store": false,
                "phone": null,
                "photo": null,
                "email": "admin@admin.com",
                "address": null,
                "role": "admin",
                "created_at": "2021-01-27T03:50:24.000000Z"
            },
            "laundry": {
                "id": "acfa7e2e-aeb9-40d6-a68c-b6c259468b6b",
                "name": "Test 01",
                "email": "gfg@jhjgj.gfu",
                "phone": "5344454",
                "address": "gfvfggfggkh",
                "photo": "http://example.com/images/3a1690bd48161f941b99af72c0098e34-1611653771.jpg",
                "verified": 1,
                "created_at": "2021-01-26T02:36:12.000000Z"
            },
            "driver": {
                "id": "7c5715e2-2e73-4103-a439-bc54d9982552",
                "dob": "17-11-1888",
                "gender": "male",
                "expire_date": "11 22",
                "plat_nu": "F 4152 FSD",
                "vehicle_brand": "Suzuki",
                "vehicle_type": "Motor",
                "no_sim": null,
                "exp_sim": null,
                "no_skck": null,
                "photo_sim": null,
                "photo_ktp": null,
                "orders": [
                    {
                        "id": "a3d9b20a-f84c-483e-81af-f8d6a7e2de0f",
                        "user_id": "2c8693d9-76ff-4bad-b7bd-bc3a1446a5e5",
                        "laundry_id": "acfa7e2e-aeb9-40d6-a68c-b6c259468b6b",
                        "driver_id": "7c5715e2-2e73-4103-a439-bc54d9982552",
                        "amount": 11000,
                        "transport": 29000,
                        "total": 183000,
                        "weight": 14,
                        "payment": "Cash",
                        "payment_id": null,
                        "payment_method": null,
                        "accepted": 0,
                        "created_at": "2021-01-31T02:21:37.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2021-01-31T02:21:37.000000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "c3d0b768-e461-48da-8dd6-c23d88562f9a",
                        "user_id": "2c8693d9-76ff-4bad-b7bd-bc3a1446a5e5",
                        "laundry_id": "acfa7e2e-aeb9-40d6-a68c-b6c259468b6b",
                        "driver_id": "7c5715e2-2e73-4103-a439-bc54d9982552",
                        "amount": 17000,
                        "transport": 15000,
                        "total": 267000,
                        "weight": 14,
                        "payment": "Cash",
                        "payment_id": null,
                        "payment_method": null,
                        "accepted": 0,
                        "created_at": "2021-02-01T02:19:25.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2021-02-01T02:19:25.000000Z"
                    }
                ],
                "created_at": "2021-01-29T04:36:23.000000Z"
            },
            "progresses": [
                {
                    "id": "6d4f502a-dab3-4419-8edf-84e73214b8be",
                    "order_id": "a3d9b20a-f84c-483e-81af-f8d6a7e2de0f",
                    "progress_id": "dc06eae1-a071-4ac0-a79d-a9c1ea737b05",
                    "created_at": "2021-01-31T02:21:37.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-01-31T02:21:37.000000Z",
                    "progress": {
                        "id": "dc06eae1-a071-4ac0-a79d-a9c1ea737b05",
                        "name": "Menginformasikan",
                        "photo": null,
                        "created_at": null,
                        "updated_at": null
                    }
                }
            ],
            "services": [
                {
                    "id": "036ff19b-91e3-47ec-8804-333f21027db7",
                    "name": null,
                    "photo": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-01-31T02:21:37.000000Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": "9a895f79-492d-416f-96ea-670567a69375",
                    "name": null,
                    "photo": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-01-31T02:21:37.000000Z"
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2021-01-31T02:21:37.000000Z"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Data are ready."
}
```

As you can see my main data has relative data under it some are objects and some are array.

**Question**

If my data was just my main item objects, I would create `data class` such as:

```
data class Orders (
    val id: String?,
    val amount: String?,
    val transport: String?,
    val total: String?,
    val weight: String?,
    val payment: String?,
    val payment_id: String?,
    val payment_method: String?,
    val accepted: String?,
) {
}
```

And all was good to go.

But my question is how to process relative data under this item so later I can place them in my fragments/activities as well? relatives are:

1. `customer` (object)
2. `laundry` (object)
3. `driver` (object -> also has array under it)
4. `progresses` (array)
5. `services` (array)

Comment: Try to use `kotlin data class file from json` extention in Android Studio. It will generate data class from your json file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

while converting api response into data class, Create data model class like below.Then access through by other data class based on your needs.

```
data class Orders(
val `data`: List<Data>,
val message: String
)


data class Data(
val accepted: Int,
val amount: Int,
val created_at: String,
val customer: Customer,
val driver: Driver,
val id: String,
val laundry: Laundry,
val payment: String,
val payment_id: Any,
val payment_method: Any,
val progresses: List<Progresse>,
val services: List<Service>,
val total: Int,
val transport: Int,
val weight: Int
 )

data class Order(
val accepted: Int,
val amount: Int,
val created_at: String,
val driver_id: String,
val id: String,
val laundry_id: String,
val payment: String,
val payment_id: Any,
val payment_method: Any,
val total: Int,
val transport: Int,
val updated_at: String,
val user_id: String,
val weight: Int
)

data class Progress(
val created_at: Any,
val id: String,
val name: String,
val photo: Any,
val updated_at: Any
)

data class Progresse(
val created_at: String,
val id: String,
val order_id: String,
val progress: Progress,
val progress_id: String,
val updated_at: String
)

data class Driver(
val created_at: String,
val dob: String,
val exp_sim: Any,
val expire_date: String,
val gender: String,
val id: String,
val no_sim: Any,
val no_skck: Any,
val orders: List<Order>,
val photo_ktp: Any,
val photo_sim: Any,
val plat_nu: String,
val vehicle_brand: String,
val vehicle_type: String
)


data class Laundry(
val address: String,
val created_at: String,
val email: String,
val id: String,
val name: String,
val phone: String,
val photo: String,
val verified: Int
)


data class Customer(
val address: Any,
val created_at: String,
val email: String,
val id: String,
val name: String,
val phone: Any,
val photo: Any,
val role: String,
val store: Boolean
)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. Is it possible to explain a bit what's going on in this code and later when for example I want go get `order->driver->id` what should I call? **also** `val customer: Customer,` and `val laundry: Laundry,` are red.

Comment: Index of item you want to get.(I am gettting first element from array) data[0].driver.id. That is all. @maftortis

Comment: Customer,Laundry added. check updated answer

Comment: @sasikumar appreciate it.

Comment: I would suggest to use  Gson or moshi instead of `val data: List<Data>,` In your Main data class. You can provide `@Json(name = "data")` in Moshi.

Comment: @shohruhMaxmudov yes I am using that

Comment: @sasikumar may i ask? `data class Data` is defined in `data class Orders(` then I also have `data class Order(` how they are falling back to each other? (i'm trying to learn this logic of your code)

Comment: @sasikumar I have problems with your solution, I cannot get data out of relative objects for instance I cannot get `laundry` data in my `for()` functionality

Comment: But making a data class manually is impossible when we look at real big apis

Answer (score 0):

you can use a plugin called JSON to kotlin. it is so useful[image of the plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCnLT.png)